# Load a Message webLink in an IFRAME

Tags: iframe, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to display a `message` using the `webLink` url returned by Microsoft Graph in an `IFrame` rather than a pop-out?

[The documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message) suggests that you can but the `webLink` response comes back with `X-Frame-Options` set to `sameorigin`.

Is there a parameter either in the initial request to Microsoft Graph or add to the `webLink` that I can add that I have missed?